# Call EE publish from another module and prepopulate some fields

Tags: channel-entries, channel, custom-fields, module

I have a custom module that members update team and player information.  I would like to use a channel for publishing match reports rather than code it into the module.

Is it possible to call the content_publish from another module and populate two fields depending on

logged in user or 
part of the link or
add information to the url

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are looking for [Channel Entries API](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/api/api_channel_entries.html#Api_channel_entries::save_entry) which you can call in your module to publish an entry whenever module's action is triggered.